# MSVC C++ complier in the Enterprise-version vs Community-version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I wonder if there is any difference between the MSVC C++ compiler in the community version and the enterprise version. For example. it is possible that some advanced optimization methods only work in the Enterprise version?

Comment: No, there is no difference.

Comment: What _commercial version_ do you mean? Trial? Or Community edition?

Comment: I mean community, I revised my question

Comment: @HansPassant can you please link here your source or reference?

Comment: At one point the static analysis features (`/analyze`) were only available in the most expensive editions, but this seems to be no longer the case.